# Как добавить изображение на фон (multi device application)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

При создании multi device application в "additional" нету TImage (При обычном VCL есть). Какие же есть способы добавить изображение на фон?

Answer (score 1):

Его переместили в раздел `Shapes`. Поиск в панели `Palette` решил бы Вашу проблему.

Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFl925XuFgc) как использовать `MultiResBitmap` для манипуляции картинками.

[image: TImage]

Comment: `F6`же емнип для быстрого описка юзают